# Output a variable into a form on another page if required

Tags: php, forms, variables

I am trying to send information from one page to another to include it into a form which is then sent via email. I have found many topics here which have helped but cant find anything for this.

I have an "enquire about this" button and I want to send that information to the form on another page however, that page might be visited directly.
How to output the information from another page I have found, brilliant news, but if I use

```
<input type="text" name="model" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($model);?>" />
```

on the form thats fine, but if a user visits that page directly then there wont be a value from a variable to complete and the form wont send.

Is there a simple solution or should I look at changing the form by using 'if exists' so that the fields change depending on whether a variable is sent or not.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why don't you make it a hidden field, thus the user can't edit it. further you could make it a "not required" field, thus if the value is not present, it'll just be blank...

Comment: Yes, I did consider both of those as options with the not required being the easiest in my mind (as a complete noob that may not be the case) lol but as Im trying to learn php I didnt want to just make it not required and see if there was a programable option but thats what I would have done if the lovely people on here hadnt helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to have a default value which is overridden if the value has already been set in POST / GET.

Edit: For Example:

```
$model = 'defaultValue';
if ($_POST['model']) {
    $model = $_POST['model'];
}
```

(This does not take account of `magic_quotes` or filtering which should be done for all inputs)

Comment: Thanks... but how do I do that? Im a real noob with php that understands the theory but isnt so good at the practical yet